# The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I got this error while trying to consume a WCF service from a C#/.NET console application:

> The type initializer for System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility threw an exception.

#### InnerException:

```
{"Configuration system failed to initialize"}
 {"Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel/serviceBehaviors.
  (C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Test.Console\\
   Test.Console\\bin\\Debug\\Test.Console.vshost.exe.Config line 7)"}
```

#### WebConfig:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ServiceConnString" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Server=.;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="debug">
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" 
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
                 maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" messageEncoding="Text" 
                 textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" 
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                        maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:26576/PersonInfoService.svc" 
                contract="PersonInfoService.IPersonInfoService" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" name="BasicHttpBinding"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the exception and checked the inner exception? It will provide much more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration file is missing the "behaviors" tag, which needs to wrap "serviceBehaviors".

```xml
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="debug">
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```