# Exception in self host wcf service - The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have got the following exception, when I tried to port an existing IIS-based [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) service to a self-hosted one.

> The type initializer for **'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility'** threw an exception.

I was following *[Self-hosted WCF REST service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/self-hosted-wcf-rest-service-or-hosting-wcf-rest-service-in-console-application)* to port my existing code, before successfully testing the sample code given in this.

My Inner exception is given below.

[image]

Now after commenting out the whole `<configSections>` tag, it throws another exception:

> The contract name **'SelfHostedRESTService.IService'** could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Service'.

Here is my configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>

  <!--<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>-->

  <!--<log4net>
    <appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="DebugLog">
      <file value="C:\\TestProj\\Info.txt" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionpattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="RestServiceLog">
      <file value="C:\\TestProj\\Error.txt" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionpattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="bmitWarningLog">
      <file value="C:\\TestProj\\PingResult.txt" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionpattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="DebugLoggerClass">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1024KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <param value="DEBUG" name="Threshold" />
      <appender-ref ref="DebugLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="SelfHostedRESTService">
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1024KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <param value="ERROR" name="Threshold" />
      <appender-ref ref="RestServiceLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="WarningLoggerClass">
      <level value="WARN" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1024KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <param value="WARN" name="Threshold" />
      <appender-ref ref="bmitWarningLog" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>-->

  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap" />
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>

    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>

    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="10:10:00" enabled="false" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="SelfHostedRESTService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="SelfHostedRESTService.RestServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="SelfHostedRESTService.Service" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SelfHostedRESTService.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SelfHostedRESTService.RestServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Here is my interface:

```
namespace Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        XmlDocument postGeneralXMLDocument(Stream strInput);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string PostMessage(string inputMessage);
    }
}
```

Why is it throwing this exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116579/the-type-initializer-for-system-servicemodel-diagnostics-traceutility)

Comment: I saw that question earlier; My Servicebehaviors tag in app.config is fine.

Comment: Have you caught the exception and looked at its inner exception?

Comment: Now I have added exception handling & updated the question. Anyway I had only one <ConfigSections> and I have commented it now. Now I have got a new exception "The contract name 'SelfHostedRESTService.IService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Service'."

Comment: That error has nothing to do with WCF or `TraceUtility`. The static ctor of TraceUtility is just the first code that trips over the issue. Your "app.config" is structurally invalid (it says in the inner exception's text). You seem to have more than one `configSections` element. You could post the content of your app.config file as well, or simply try to correct it on your own.

Comment: Don't comment `configSections` out, make sure it is the first sub element of `configuration`. Anyhow, the error you now see seems to be a different issue. Does your `Service` class actually implement the `IService` interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your actual inner exception,

`Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element.`

The cause of problem is `<startup>..</startup>` section, if `<configSections>` is present in web.config it must be first child of root  element. Moving `<startup>..</startup>` section after `<configSections>` will resolve your problem.

1. Uncomment  `<configSections>` element.
2. Move `<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>` section below the `<configSections>...</configSections>` section.

---

**Update**:

For exception `"The contract name 'SelfHostedRESTService.IService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Service'."`

Please correct the namespace used, its mismatch in namespace used in interface & web.config.

In Contract: `namespace Contracts`

In Web.config: `SelfHostedRESTService.IService`

Either,

- Change namespace to `SelfHostedRESTService` in Interface

OR Alternatively

- Use `Contracts.IService` in web.config.

---

**Update 2**
For Exception `"Operation 'postGeneralXMLDocument' in contract 'IService' has a query variable named 'strInput' of type 'System.IO.Stream', but type 'System.IO.Stream' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'. Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'."`
 Seems you are using some variable named 'strInput' of type 'System.IO.Stream', which directly can't be serialized. Try serialize to string & then deserialize at other end.

One useful link is :
[http://www.techques.com/question/1-5241661/WCF-Complex-JSON-INPUT-Error-(not-convertible-by-QueryStringConverter)](http://www.techques.com/question/1-5241661/WCF-Complex-JSON-INPUT-Error-%28not-convertible-by-QueryStringConverter%29)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did as you suggested. But got the same exception. Please see me updated question and new exception "The contract name 'SelfHostedRESTService.IService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Service'."

Comment: did you uncommented `<configSections>`?

Comment: Yes, and moved above to make the first element.

Comment: Its altogether different problem than previous. Please show your service contract interface, its something related to mismatch in config & actual file/method names.

Comment: @SebastianXavier , Updated answer for solution to problem.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I think, its partially resolved. Now I have an entirely different issue.. "Operation 'postGeneralXMLDocument' in contract 'IService' has a query variable named 'strInput' of type 'System.IO.Stream', but type 'System.IO.Stream' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.  Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'."

Comment: :) Yes, its nowhere related to previous two issues. Seems you are using some variable named 'strInput' of type 'System.IO.Stream', which directly can't be serialized. Try serialize to string & then deserialize at other end.

Comment: Try http://www.techques.com/question/1-5241661/WCF-Complex-JSON-INPUT-Error-(not-convertible-by-QueryStringConverter)

Comment: Thanks; It got solved. But I have another problem; I have posted it here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015787/selfhost-wcf-service-how-to-pass-stream-variables

Comment: If it helped, you can always upvote or mark as answer, as this will help others with same problem to find the solution.